# Sliding mode surface derivative exact matrix format (ds/dx)

Tags: control-engineering, aerospace-engineering, numerical-methods

Is there any suggestion on sliding surface state  derivative matrix (ds/dx) format?

```
ds/dx = [ds/beta,ds/dalpha,ds/dp,ds/dq,ds/dr,ds/dphi;
         ds/beta,ds/dalpha,ds/dp,ds/dq,ds/dr,ds/dphi;
         ds/beta,ds/dalpha,ds/dp,ds/dq,ds/dr,ds/dphi];
```

or

```
ds/dx = [0,0,ds/dp,0,0,ds/dphi;
         ds/beta,0,0,0,ds/dr,0;
         0,ds/dalpha,0,ds/dq,0,0];
```

problem described below

In the article [Controller Design using Bifurcation Map for Aircraft Spin Recovery](http://www.wseas.us/e-library/conferences/2009/lalaguna/MANOCO/MANOCO17.pdf), the sliding surface derivative is obtained using a numerical method.

The steady space system is defined by the following equations:

$$\dot{\underline{x}}=A(\underline{x},t)+B(\underline{x},t)\underline{U}, \\
\underline{x}=[V,\alpha,\beta,p,q,r,\phi,\theta], \\
s=\left[\begin{array}{c}
\dfrac{d}{dt}(\phi-\phi_d)+\lambda_1(\phi-\phi_d) \\
\dfrac{d}{dt}(\alpha-\alpha_d)+\lambda_2(\alpha-\alpha_d) \\
\dfrac{d}{dt}(\beta-\beta_d)+\lambda_3(\beta-\beta_d) \\
\end{array}\right]$$

where $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ are positive real numbers.

The article states:

> The control law from reaching law in Eq. (6) can be derived
>   as:
>   $$\dot{s}=\dfrac{\partial{s}}{\partial{x}}\dot{x}=\dfrac{\partial{s}}{\partial{x}}(A+Bu)=-Qsgn(s)+Kf(s).\tag{8}$$
>
> By solving the above equation (8) for u (3 x 1), one gets expressions
>   for u as:
>
> $$u=-\left(\dfrac{\partial{s}}{\partial{x}}B\right)^{-1}\left[\dfrac{\partial{s}}{\partial{x}}A+Qsgn(S)+Kf(s)\right].\tag{9}$$
>
> The matrix $\frac{\partial{s}}{\partial{x}}$ is computed numerically.
>   The control inputs computed are subject to position and rate
>   constraints on control surface deflections as listed in the Table 1.

How would be the exact form of matrix of $\dfrac{\partial s}{\partial x}$ (element of $\dfrac{\partial s}{\partial x}$ in columns and raws)?

Comment: This looks like it's the same as your previous question, with the part about the numerical method removed...

Comment: Mr Dan , Last question was about the method and asked by Lahidj.I've edited the question and follow it but the question remained open in last part and not answered."How would be the exact form of matrix of (ds/dx) (element of ds/dx) in columns and raws)?"